# Where to Download JDBC Driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, driver

I was googling and couldn't quite tell which JDBC driver to download that my search results returned.  I'm using the latest version of MySQL (Community Edition) and running Glassfish 3.0 (If that has any relevance?) also I'm using java 6.

Which driver should I download that would be compatible with my current setup? I really did try and do my research but the fact that there are so many different drivers and from difference sources makes it a tad confusing for some.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could download a [JDBC Driver for MySQL (Connector/J)](http://www.mysql.com/products/connector/).

Comment: Thanks very much, where exactly do I put this file? Under glassfish > lib ?

Comment: @DeanGrobler, I am not familiar with GlassFish. The jar must be in your `CLASSPATH`. So if the `lib` folder is part of your CLASSPATH then it should work.

Comment: are there any better alternatives to ConnectorJ ?